# how to convert a normally closed curcuit to normally open

Tags: switching-transients

Just got a problem at work and I need help fixing it.

I have a water meter that is normally closed and after 5 litres of water has been used it opens that circuit, now the input board that I have been given reads a NC as a read.

So, I was wondering what is the easiest way of changing the circuit to allow me to have a NO circuit going NC.

Thanks

Comment: A schematic diagram would be a massive help here as this is one of the vaguest descriptions of methods I have ever read

Comment: Besides the schematic: Use sentences and punctuation instead of one-flow-of-words-in-one-long-sentence. Your questions is extremely hard to read as it is now.

Comment: fair point, let me see if i can clean that up for you

Comment: What does "reads a NC as a read" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to probably use a NC relay, along with a small DC power supply (wall wart) appropriate to the relay’s coil voltage and current draw.

You’ll need to determine the maximum voltage and current that your NC contact is rated to handle. Also, you should add a reverse bias diode across the coil as a snubber to avoid arcing across your existing contacts.

By using a normally-closed contact on the relay, you’ll effectively invert the NC closure, turning it into an NO closure.